# How to iterate through XML file efficiently in python with spacy phrasematcher

Tags: python, xml, spacy

I'm trying to iterate through a Japanese to English dictionary [here](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/j_jmdict.html), which is stored as an XML file. I don't need all the parts of it, all I need is to be able to select a part of speech and sort for all entries that have that given part of speech tag:

```
<pos>&n;</pos>
<pos>&vs;</pos>
```

More details on the [type declaration for the XML](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/jmdict_dtd_h.html)

Now, I'm wondering what the best way to iterate through all entries with a given POS. This is subject to change, but I'm only interested in extracting certain parts, probably these:

```
<k_ele>
<keb>収集</keb>
<ke_pri>ichi1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>news1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>nf05</ke_pri>
</k_ele>
<k_ele>
<keb>蒐集</keb>
</k_ele>
<k_ele>
<keb>拾集</keb>
</k_ele>
<k_ele>
<keb>収輯</keb>
</k_ele>
```

Some pseudocode:

```
For all Ichidan verbs in the XML file:
ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ICHIDANVERB", "pattern": x.text} for x in word.kanji_forms])
ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ICHIDANVERB", "pattern": x.text} for x in word.kana_forms])
```

perhaps with an option to ignore okurigana

What would be the most efficient way to do this? There are hundreds of thousands of entries.
Thank you very much.

EDIT: proposed solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = r"C:\Users\NameRedacted\Desktop\JMdict"
tree = ET.parse(path)

print("Search the entire tree for entries with '&n;' pos")

# "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)" must be used instead of the entity version "&n;" as defined in the DTD
for entry in tree.findall("./entry/sense/[pos='noun (common) (futsuumeishi)']/.."):

  for k_ele in entry.findall("./k_ele"):

    for keb in k_ele.findall("./keb"):
      # Do something with every keb of the k_ele
        print(keb)
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "NOUNS", "pattern": (keb)}])
  for r_ele in entry.findall("./r_ele"):

    for reb in k_ele.findall("./reb"):
      # Do something with every reb of the r_ele
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "NOUNS", "pattern": (reb)}])
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to parse the XML file into an in-memory tree and use XPath to find the elements that you want. This would require enough memory, but you would be able to query the tree multiple times if needed.

Example:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('JMdict_e')

print("Search the entire tree for entries with '&n;' pos")

# "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)" must be used instead of the entity version "&n;" as defined in the DTD
for entry in tree.findall("./entry/sense/[pos='noun (common) (futsuumeishi)']/.."):
  # Do something with every entry
  for k_ele in entry.findall("./k_ele"):
    # Do something with every k_ele of the entry
    for keb in k_ele.findall("./keb"):
      # Do something with every keb of the k_ele
      pass
    for ke_pri in k_ele.findall("./ke_pri"):
      # Do something with every ke_pri of the k_ele
      pass

# Delete the tree when no longer needed to release the memory
del tree
```

[The documentation of xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) shows the supported XPath syntax.

See a demo in [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r6DuqNvcWku1WC2YCBe5VzOLq7hqkd6m). In this test with an XML of 51 MB (only English translations) the memory increased ~500 MB after parsing the file into the in-memory tree. Parsing the tree took ~4 s and querying it ~3 s.

Comment: This is incredibly, incredibly helpful. Thanks for taking the time. I've been struggling with this for days. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: please see the updated code in my original question at the bottom. Two things: 1, it seems printing the elements give memory addresses. When I try to pass the reb and keb elements into my phrase-matcher, I don't think it is recognizing the phrases. Is the address passed in as a string? Or is it implicitly dereferenced?

Comment: @johnrabbit, the demo in Colab shows how to get the text of an element, e. g.: `"".join(keb.itertext())`.

Comment: I saw that, would keb.text give the same result?

Comment: @johnrabbit, no. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text): "To collect the inner text of an element, see [itertext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext), for example `"".join(element.itertext())`."